# Как ускорить отладку shell-скрипта для zsh?

Tags: macos, shell, отладка, zsh

Пишу функцию на shell для zsh. Размещаю ее в файле `.zshrc` своего пользователя. Чтобы заработала — нужно выйти из ОС и залогиниться снова. Это довольно долго, неудобно пробовать варианты.

Как я могу ускорить этот процесс? Может я вообще неправильным путем функцию устанавливаю в систему?

zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0), OS X 10.10.4,

Comment: А зачем выходить из системы? Zsh должен обработать `.zshrc` при каждом запуске, так что вполне достаточно запускать новый `zsh` в терминале и прибивать по завершении отладки. Также можно писать функцию в отдельном файле, а дебажить с помощью `zsh <имя файла>` (или сделать его исполняемым).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

достаточно просто запустить новый экземпляр `zsh`: открыть новое окно эмулятора терминала или прямо в текущем запустить:

```
$ zsh
```

во втором случае имеет смысл после опробования выполнять `exit` (часто у этой команды есть эквивалент в виде сочетания клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>).

возможно, будет достаточно и просто сохранять функцию в отдельный файл и интерпретировать его одним из [двух](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-source) эквивалентных [способов](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e):

```
$ source файл
$ . файл
```

Answer (score 1):

### Перезагрузка

`source ~/.zshrc` может породить тучу неправильных багов если очень много всяких финтов. Например, если есть такая строчка:

```
alias .="open ."
```

Которая при попытке использовать `. file.sh` открывает и `.`, и `file` **Finder**-ом.

На **Linux** я бы сделал так:

```
zsh;exit
# что-то изменили
zsh;exit
...
```

Так как ты на **OS X**, то я могу подсказать более удобное решение.

```
if [ $(uname) = Darwin ]; then
    ZSHRC_TERMINAL=$TERM_PROGRAM
    [ "$ZSHRC_TERMINAL" = Apple_Terminal ] && ZSHRC_TERMINAL=Terminal
    alias n="osascript -e 'tell application $ZSHRC_TERMINAL to activate' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to tell process $ZSHRC_TERMINAL to keystroke "t" using { command down }' | zsh"
    alias nx="n;exit"
fi
```

Теперь при написании `$ nx` Открывается новая табуляция в `Terminal` или `iTerm` и закрывается старая. Схема предполагает, что при выходе из сессии табуляция закрывается.

Для удобства работы с `OS X` я создал себе очень-очень давно одну программку на `C++11`, которую потом немножко отредактировал из-за туч быдлокода.

http://pastebin.com/MFENLZRE

Программа принимает два параметра: процесс и что нажимать.

### Инструменты отладки

`$ sudo easy_install pygmentize`

```
alias ccat="pygmentize -g" # cat с подсветкой синтаксиса
ansi () {
    printf "\033[$1"
}
getfunc () { # вывод кода функции по ее имени. $ getfunc getfunc
    declare -f "$*" | pygmentize -l bash
}
geta() { # поиск строки по маске в указанных файлах
    for i in ~/.zshrc; do
        [ -e "$i" ] || continue
        [ -z "$(cat "$i" | grep "$1")" ] && printf "$(ansi '0;1;40;37m')  ...Skipped $(ansi '97m')$(basename $i)$(ansi '0m')\n" || {
            local space=10
            local scr="`basename $i`"
            local line=$((60 - ${#scr} / 2 - $space))
            line=$(printf "="%.0s `seq $line`)
            space=$(printf " "%.0s `seq $space`)
            ansi '0;1;40;93m'
            printf "$line$space$(ansi '5;40;92m')$scr$(ansi '0;1;40;93m')$space$line"
            ansi '0m'
            echo
            cat "$i" | grep --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,.cvs,.git,.hg,.svn} "$1" | pygmentize -l bash | gsed "s/^/+    /g"
            printf "$(ansi '9;1;40;93m')`perl -e 'printf "="x120;'`$(ansi '0m')\n"
    done
}
```

Также не забываем использовать `return` для отлаживания `~/.zshrc` по частям.

### Источники:

[Shell : get function's body by it's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305791/shell-get-functions-body-by-its-name)

[Rosetta Code : Repeated string](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#UNIX_Shell)

Comment: *Так как ты на OS X, то я могу подсказать более удобное решение* — не знаком с *apple/osx*, потому и спрашиваю: это что, такой хитрый способ открыть новое окно эмулятора виртуального терминала? разве *shortcut*-ами (если они там существуют) не проще ли?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, [это язык AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript). На Linux я с графическим интерфейсом не очень дружу, как там - не знаю таких хаков.

Comment: я обновлял комментарий. перечитайте. пожалуйста, и, если он не совсем глупый, ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет, не проще. Одно дело - вы нажимаете cmd-t cmd-shift-left cmd-w, другое - `$ nx`. Это проще и удобнее для частого употребления. Оно нажимает Cmt-t и выходит `exit` из прошлой табуляции.

Comment: а, понял. вы предлагаете закрывать существующую сессию. мне кажется, при отладке чего-нибудь типа *shell**rc*** это может быть довольно «взрывоопасно»: например, если при ошибке в *rc*-файле *shell* вообще не запустится.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin запустится. к тому же, никто не мешает иметь две вкладки : одну старую, другую непостоянную. К тому же 1) после 10 ошибок интерпретация прекращается 2) я редактировал это много-много раз, и более удобного способа не нашел. 3) он запускается до **rc** файла. Если **rc** файл содержит ошибку, то провалится скрипт, а не сам интерпретатор. 4) не проверить скрипт невозможно.

Comment: *запустится* — обычно да, но ошибки при написании новой функциональности бывают разные. например, команда `exit` в *rc*-файле.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, тогда **google** в помощь: [exit in bashrc](http://serverfault.com/questions/206544/i-screwed-up-exit-in-bashrc). Также см. изменения в ответе.

Comment: *google в помощь* — забавные ответы. особенно яркие эмоции порождает набравший больше всего голосов практически бесполезный (при нынешней производительности компьютеров) совет нажимать *ctrl+c*. подозреваю, что голосовали исключительно «ради хохмы». p.s. «exit в rc-файле» — это всего лишь первый приходящий в голову пример, как можно «исправить» rc-файл так, чтобы *shell* не запускался.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. pygmentize — это же для Питона инструмент, разве нет? Для закрытия старой и открытия новой вкладки вроде достаточно Cmd+W, Cmd+T.

Comment: `pygmentize -g` - это инструмент, написанный на Питоне, да. @alexanderbarakin, в интернете три правила: 1) все, что вас интересует, уже кому-то было нужно. 2) Все, что никому до этого не было нужно, можно спросить на **stachexchange**. 3) Все, что нельзя спросить или найти, не является конкретной проблемой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin,  `osascript` - это довольно удобная штука для работы конкретно с **Mac OS X**. Можно как минимум автоматизировать нажатие клавиш, но вообще можно намного большее. Лично я этим не очень интересуюсь, потому что больше мне никогда нужно не было.

Comment: @theoden: спасибо, ознакомился. Идея в том, чтобы нажатия клавиш автоматизировать через консольные команды?

Comment: @theoden, *в интернете три правила* — ну, скажем так, ни сайты сети stackexchange, ни даже поисковики, — по-моему, не являются какой-то «альфой и омегой» интернета. интернет, всё-таки, несколько пошире будет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да. Когда такое делается много раз, лучше автоматизировать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, предлагаю дискуссию на этом закрыть.

Comment: @theoden: мне кажется, автоматизировать Cmd+W, Cmd+T — это слишком сложно. Или вы что-то другое предлагаете? Я там кусок про pygmentize не очень понял.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я изменил чуть-чуть. забыл добавить ` | zsh` после текста команды. Сейчас должно работать. Про `pygmentize` : чтобы увидеть эффект, напиши `cat ~/.zshrc | pygmentize -l 'bash'`.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку я работаю в оболочке iTerm, в моем случае было достаточно любого из вариантов:

- открыть новую вкладку
- выполнить `zsh`

Проверил, что в обоих случаях файл `.zshrc` читается заново и доступна обновленная версия функции.